# Adding \paragraph sections inside abstract package's onecolabstract environment

Tags: sections-paragraphs, abstract

I am having trouble using `\paragraph{}` inside the `onecolabstract` environment. The desired goal would look something like this:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{abstract}
\title{Minimal Example}
\author{DocBuckets}
\begin{document}
\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{onecolabstract}
        \textbf{Background} Abstract background text...

        \textbf{Methods and Results} Abstract methods text...

        \textbf{Conclusions} Abstract conclusions text...
    \end{onecolabstract}
]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Methods}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

But I want to use `\paragraph{Background}`, `\paragraph{Methods and Results}`, etc. instead of the `\textbf{}` alternatives I use in the minimal example. When I try this, I get all sorts of errors.

Perhaps relatedly, I also got errors when trying to use the `\lipsum[1]` method to generate abstract paragraphs in the minimal example I give. I suspect the problem is the same for `\lipsum` and `\paragraph` in `onecolabstract`. Is there something I can do to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onecolabstract` is a list type environment so is not expecting to see sectional headings etc. as produced by the `\paragraph` command.  Instead you can box the material up in a minipage:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{abstract}

\title{Minimal Example}
\author{DocBuckets}

\begin{document}


\twocolumn[
    \maketitle
    \begin{onecolabstract}
      \begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
        \paragraph{Background} Abstract background text describing
        enough to place this in context and make the reader
        sufficiently curious to indulge their time in this wonderful work\dots

        \paragraph{Methods and Results} Abstract methods text and some
        extraordinary results\dots

        \paragraph{Conclusions} Abstract conclusions text.

      \end{minipage}
    \end{onecolabstract}
]
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\section{Methods}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

I presume your abstract is not too long, so that it fits on the current page.  You may want to adjust some of the paraments set by the `abstract` package to improve the vertical spacing in the `onecolabstract`.

Comment: This worked nicely. I was originally trying to fiddle with minipages but only ended up making a bigger mess of things. I'll have to remember the minipage-in-environments trick.